# Loop Until A Key Is Pressed Java

Tags: java, loops, input

How do I stop a loop when a certain key is pressed.I want to create an average calculator where you input numbers and it will give you the average.I made a counter for the amount of numbers that is being entered.However I need to stop this counter when the user is done inputting all the numbers they need.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Use branching statements: break, continue or return. More here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Answer (score 4):

You can always listen to a `KeyEvent` in Java.

This is a sample code,

```
import java.awt.KeyEventDispatcher;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class IsKeyPressed {
    private static boolean wPressed = false;
    public static boolean isWPressed() {
        synchronized (IsKeyPressed.class) {
            return wPressed;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addKeyEventDispatcher((KeyEventDispatcher) new KeyEventDispatcher() {

            @Override
            public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent ke) {
                synchronized (IsKeyPressed.class) {
                    switch (ke.getID()) {
                    case KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED:
                        if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
                            wPressed = true;
                        }
                        break;

                    case KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED:
                        if (ke.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
                            wPressed = false;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And in your code you can do this,

```
if (IsKeyPressed.isWPressed()) {
    // do something
}
```

You can obviously expand this to other key mappings too.

Comment: Is your problem solved? If yes, please do consider to accept or up vote this answer. It took a lot of time for me to write this detailed answer just to help you.